# Addition and semicolon in assembly language

Tags: assembly, addition, ijvm

Can someone explain me what the semicolon do in ADD R1, R1; R2?
I know that ADD, addition R1 and R2, and puts the value into R1. Does it do the same here? The first picture is the instruction set we are using. The second picture shows the IJVM architecture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p54ie.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exUT3.png)

Comment: What architecture are you talking about?  And what assembler?  Syntax varies with assembler even for the same ISA (machine-code format).  In some asm syntaxes, `;` is a comment character, e.g. for many Intel-syntax x86 assemblers like NASM and MASM, but x86 doesn't have registers called R1 or R2.

Comment: I've updated the post with the instructions set and the architecture. Maybe this update helps.

Comment: Your ISA reference shows that `add` is a 3-operand instruction, with two commas separating the 3 operands.  A semicolon is probably a typo for a comma, so it should be `r1 += r2` as `add r1, r1, r2` or equivalently `add r1, r2, r1`.

Comment: @Wheil For the future, please avoid posting pictures of text if possible.

Comment: What semicolon are you talking about? There is no semicolon in your pictures.